# Creating a smooth transition between activites in android application

Tags: android

I have a task on my mobile development (Android) course to create an application, that translates a word and shows ten images, which refer to this word. So I've done everything, but I want to have the time of switching the activities filled with something. Progress bar or something like that.

Here is my code of application: https://github.com/baba-beda/translate

So my question is: what should I better use?

I used your advice with animation. But I still have a problem, that second activity loads quite long time, and application, unfortunately, is still subject to inconvenient pauses.

Comment: Hey @Daria Zenkova you can apply transition effect while switching from one to other activity.

Answer (score 1):

Please Apply Transition effect using (for eg.anim/fade_in.xml file) xml file.

Use This link.i hope its useful to you.

[reference demo link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/04/custom-animation-while-switching.html)